# Point Sampling tool Overlapping buffered points

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point

I am trying to extract some sampling data... I have Yield data (blue), planting data (green), and Spreading data(red).

I left the yield data as a point since it is the most dense data I have. What I did was take the other data and use the fixed buffer tool to create points the size of the pass (30ft for planting, 90ft for spreading)

[image]

When I did the point sampling tool I only got the Yield data with two empty columns for product and spreading rate.

What is causing the lack of data? Could it be the overlapping data points for the planter and spreading data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point sampling tool works perfectly if the spatial reference are same for all data. If the point and polygon data have different spatial references (different projections), the output will be point data with empty field for other data.

Comment: I had one layer is WGS84 and the other two in NAD84.. I switched them all to NAD84 and it corrected the issue.

Comment: Glad it worked.